# EF 4.1 Code First MVC3 App and Facebook Share Feature

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, facebook-sharer

I am working on a simple web application made using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First approach and MVC3.

The web application is a simple Quotes website, and on its homepage, the user get a list of quotes. What I would like to do is have a Facebook Share button, like so:

[image]

And when a user clicks that button, I want the ***Quote author image, along with his quote and his name*** to be ***posted on the user's Facebook wall***. I believe they call this Share Functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing Rich Media
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

you should be able to populate the title, image and description tags to get something similar to what you want.

Comment: Thank You Betty. I'll give it a try and let you know how I got on. Will come back and mark your post as answer if all goes well. :)

Comment: it says that [ The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button ]. And when I go to the Like button, it is very confusing ! It asks for the URL to like .. but I have many quotes listed on a page, and so each quote does not have a URL.

Can you please advice on how I should proceed. The Fb info is not very clear. :(

Comment: Add anchor links to all the quotes? eg server.com/path/to/page#1231