# Share with Facebook in MVC 3

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-sharer

I'm developing an application online in MVC 3 who consists to manage a tennis club...

When a tennis player make a reservation for a tennis game, I would like to allow this tennis player to share his game with Facebook...

Is it possible ?

I have found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589479/ef-4-1-code-first-mvc3-app-and-facebook-share-feature) but no more...

Have you an idea or some tutorials ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [C# Facebook SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/). For example to post to the wall as shown in the [documentation](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests):

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = "My first wall post using Facebook C# SDK" });
var newPostId = result.id;
```

Comment: I think the above approach is not recommended for Francesco situation because to share content to Facebook using graph API (in case of C# Facebook SDK) will require to create app, and get the user's permission to authorize that app before sharing.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways

1. You can use the graph api. (but i would recommend it for more complex interaction)
2. But the most simple one is to start sharing using the following url.

   https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&t=

For details you can refer to [Facebook documentations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 key ways in which you could achieve this:

**Option 1 - Server-Side** ([Facebook for Websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/))

Upon creation, your server could post to the users wall, if the user desires. This would be slightly more complicated to set-up, but would be more automated. You would need to set-up an app-id and ask the user to authenticate their facebook details.

**Option 2 - Client-side** ([Facebook Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/))

After creation, the user could be prompted with a `Share` or `Like` button, that would in turn post it to his or her wall. This would require the user an extra click, but would be more straight forward to set-up.

Answer (score 0):

A Step by step tutorial is available [here](http://instinctcoder.com/add-facebook-twitter-google-plus-share-button-in-asp-net-mvc-4-2/) to integrate social plugin into mvc